# Python list/dict comparisons performance

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I am trying to compare two objects to each other.

One object is a list of files and their metadata (from Dropbox), and the other is a list of rows returned from a query (SqlAlchemy).

The goal is to remove duplicates from files based on their existence in the DB.

Total files = 6716
Total entries in Database = 397

```
#get dropbox files
files = get_dropbox_files(client, path)

#get rows from Database
exists_row = exists_results.fetchall()

todelete = {}

#start timer
tic = timeit.default_timer()
for k, v in files.iteritems():
    for row in exists_row:
        if row.rev == v['rev'] and row.revision == v['revision']:
            todelete[k] = k

if todelete is not None:
    for t in todelete:
        files.pop(t)

toc = timeit.default_timer()

print toc - tic
```

This prints 2.6 seconds. This seems pretty long, although given 6716 * 397 = 2,666,252 iterations, might not be unreasonable. At any rate, is there a more performant way of accomplishing my goal of removing existent items?

Comment: Do you care about any other fields in `row`?

Comment: what are the data types for `v['rev']` and `v['revision']` ?

Comment: This seems like a job for `set` objects ... Membership tests are much quicker there ...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - not interested in any other fields in row.

Comment: @Gabriel v['rev'] is unicode and v['revision'] is int

Comment: I like the @mgilson idea. make two sets, one with tuples of `rev` and `revision` from the files and one from the database.  Then a union will tell you where you have entries in both.

Comment: @Gabriel I would still need to keep the other data part of v in moving forward

Comment: @egekhter did this speed up your algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first attempt at the `set` solution discussed in the comments,

```
set_db = set( (row.rev,row.revision) for row in exists_row )
for k,v in files.items():
    if (v['rev'],v['revision']) in set_db:
        del(files[k])
```

It gets rid of one explicit `for` loop.  Sets and dictionaries are implemented as hash tables in Python so membership checking should be O(1).

Comment: I don't think the union operation is necessary, from the sounds of things `set_db` would be a subset of `set_file` so `set_union` would just equal `set_db`. Even if that assumption is not true checking for membership in `set_db` is still O(1) so it's probably not worth the effort to create `set_file` and `set_union`. Also you can't use `iteritems` while removing objects from a dict, and using `del files[k]` should be marginally faster than using `pop`.

Comment: I tested this out and execution went down from 28 seconds to .5 seconds. Problem is that when I print files I get {}

Comment: did you use `set_check = set_db` or `set_check = set_union` ? are you sure all the files weren't supposed to be deleted?

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it got me pointing in the right direction.
Final workable code:
    `set_db = set((row.rev, row.revision) for row in exists_row) for k, v in files.items():`
       
    `if (v['rev'], v['revision']) in set_db:
            del(files[k])`

Comment: sounds good. i'll update the answer to reflect what worked for you.